# Display nav over an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a simple question but I'm just starting to learn HTML/CSS.
I want to display an iframe in full screen, which I can do, but I also want to display my nav menu over it.

My html looks like this :

```
<body>
     <nav>
         (menu items)
     </nav>
     <iframe src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"/>
</body>
```

The problem is that I can only see the nav menu before the iframe loads, then it disappears below the iframe.

How could I display it on the top ? (like this : http://puu.sh/kK6Eu/e55531777f.png)

Thanks. (sorry for my english, I'm french)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
<body>
     <nav style="position: relative; z-index: 2;">
         Hello
     </nav>
     <iframe src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"/>
</body>
```

Comment: If I remove the position: absolute; the nav displays above / before the iframe

Comment: you want the nav bar over the iframe and on a top position??

Comment: check if this helps you

<body>
     <nav style="position: relative; z-index: 2;">
         Hello
     </nav>
     <iframe src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"/>
</body>

Comment: Ok I added the z-index and position properties, now it works ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the nav element's Z-index in its CSS properties.
Higher Z-index means higher elements

```
nav{
   z-index: 2
}

iframe{
   z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with adding position property it works fine !